# In lambda calculus, can variable be expression in general?

Tags: variables, lambda-calculus

For better understanding of functional programming, I am reading the wiki page for lambda calculus [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Definition).

The definition says:

> If x is a variable and M ∈ Λ, then (λx.M) ∈ Λ

Intuitively I thought variable are / represented by single-letter id's. But since here we deal with strict math definitions, I just want to double confirm this understanding: in general, can expression be classified as variable?

e.g. if `x` is a variable, is expression `(x + x)` a variable in lambda calculus? i.e. is it ok to write (λ(x+x).M) as an lambda calculus abstraction?

(Concern is in some context this is true. e.g. [Here](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/variables.html): `An expression such as 4x^3 is a variable`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `(x + x)` is no variable (indeed it's not even a expression in naive lambda calculus).
I think you mix the terms **variables** and **expressions** somehow (or want some kind of pattern-matching?).

So let's follow the core-definition of lambda-calculus and **expressions**:

The definition itself is not that hard (indeed you linked it yourself with the wiki-page).
It's mentioned right from the start:

- you have a set of variables **V**: (`v_1, v_2, ...`) (of course you can name them as you want - it's only important that you remmber that these are considered *different* **symbols** in your calculus)
- the symbols `λ`, `.`, `(` and `)`

This is it - thats all of the "*Tokens*" for this *grammar*/calculus.

Now there are a couple of rules how you can form **Expressions** from these:

- each Variable is a expression
- **Abstraction**: if `E` is a expression and `x` is a Variable then `(λx.E)` is a expression (here `x` and `E` are *templates* or *Metavariables* - you have to fill them with some real Expression to make this an Expression!)
- **Application**: if `A` and `B` are expressions than `(A B)` is a expression.

So possible expressions are:

- `v_50`
- `(λv_4.v_5)`
- `((λv_4.v_5) v_50)`
- ....

This is all when it comes to expressions.

You see: if you don't *allow* `(x+x)` as a symbol or name for a variable from the start it can never be a variable - indeed no expression is a variable even if there are some expressions consisting only of one said variable - if you called something expression it will never be a variable (again) ;)

PS: of course there are a couple of conventions to keep the parentheses a bit *down* - but for a start you don't need those.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Symbol sounds like a more reasonable name.